# Declaration merging for Joi types

Tags: typescript

I want to narrow the `type` property of the [ValidationErrorItem](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/lib/index.d.ts#L655) from `Joi` using declaration merging.

The interface in Joi looks like this:

```js
declare namespace Joi {
   interface ValidationErrorItem {
        message: string;
        path: Array<string | number>;
        type: string;
        context?: Context;
    }
}
```

My `index.d.ts` in `src/types` looks like this:

```js
import { Context } from 'joi'

declare namespace Joi {
  type ValidationErrorItemType = 'any.required' | 'date.format'
  export interface ValidationErrorItem {
    message: string
    path: Array<string | number>
    type: ValidationErrorItemType
    context?: Context
  }
}
```

This is my `include` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
 "include": ["src/**/*", "types/types.d.ts"]
```

However, VS Code still shows `type` to be of type string instead of `ValidationErrorItem` and when using it in a `switch` statement I can still use any string without getting compiler warnings.

**Update**

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "types/joi.ts"]
}
```

This is my `joi.d.ts` based on the answer from @tymzap:

```js
declare module 'joi' {
  // full path to joi typings is used to avoid circular import path
  import type { Context } from 'joi/lib/index'
  export { default } from 'joi/lib/index'

  type ValidationErrorItemType = 'any.required' | 'date.format'

  export type ValidationErrorItem = {
    message: string
    path: Array<string | number>
    type: ValidationErrorItemType
    context?: Context
  }
}
```

This is my sample usage:

```js
error.details.map((i) => {
    const x: ValidationErrorItem = i as ValidationErrorItem
    switch (x.type) {
      case 'any.required':
        break

      default:
        break
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't narrow the type using interface merging. This operation **extends** types, not **overrides** them. Extending `ValidationErrorItemType` with `string` gives `ValidationErrorItemType | string`, that's why you still can use any `string`.

To achieve this you can redeclare Joi module. Modify the type to your needs and export it after reexporting original Joi typings.

joi.d.ts:

```
declare module 'joi' {
  // full path to joi typings is used to avoid circular import path
  import type { Context } from 'joi/lib/index';
  export * from 'joi/lib/index';
  export { default } from 'joi/lib/index';

  type ValidationErrorItemType = 'any.required' | 'date.format';

  export type ValidationErrorItem = {
    message: string;
    path: Array<string | number>;
    type: ValidationErrorItemType;
    context?: Context;
  }
}
```

Test:

```
import type { ValidationErrorItem } from 'joi';

const test: ValidationErrorItem = {
  // error: Type '"wrong.type"' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrorItemType'.
  type: 'wrong.type',
  message: 'dummy message',
  path: ['dummy-path'],
};
```

This way you can effectively override given type from library, without merging with its original signature.

Edit: Joi uses old `export =` syntax, depending on your compiler settings this could lead to errors based on typings flavour incompatibility. In this case you can add this line to tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this error for `joi.d.ts`: `Module '"node_modules/joi/lib/index"' uses 'export =' and cannot be used with 'export *'.ts(2498)` and when using it I get this error: `Type 'import("node_modules/joi/lib/index").ValidationErrorItem' is not assignable to type 'import("joi").ValidationErrorItem'. Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrorItemType'.ts(2322)`

Comment: However when I make an explicit cast like this, it works without `ts2322` error: `const x: ValidationErrorItem = i as ValidationErrorItem` but it would be great if it can be avoided.

Comment: What version of Joi do you use? Could you share your tsconfig? Unfortunately different libraries uses different modules/export conventions which can produce bugs like this.

Comment: If you cast this inside declaration file I would go for it, it is common practice to define variables and cast them inside `.d.ts` files.

Comment: I'm using version 17.5.0. I'm not casting inside my `joi.d.ts` file but in the usage. Can you explain how to cast in the `d.ts` file? I've updated my question with the changes I made.

Comment: For this case I recommend using `"skipLibCheck": true` to skip type checking of declaration files. I updated answer with this

Comment: Found my mistake: I was including `joi.ts` instead of `joi.d.ts` in my `tsconfig.json`. Both ts errors are gone now even without explicit cast.