# How to override type declaration generated by Prisma?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have a node/typescript project that is using Prisma as an ORM and the underlying database used is sqlite. Prisma does [not support enums when using sqlite](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2219) which removes the ability to narrow down string types to a set of specific strings. In my case, I have a `User` model defined which has a property `role`. I want `role` to only take the value of `"ADMIN"` or `"MEMBER"` but given that I use sqlite it's only possible to get the type of `role` as a generic `string`.

What I want to do now is to override the type definition for `User` which is generated by prisma and manually set the `role` type to `"ADMIN" | "MEMBER"`. Since prisma generates a module with the type declarations inside of `node_modules` I thought the answer would be straightforward as there are many posts/resources on overriding types of libraries. With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70784451/12794481) I ended up adding a declaration file `index.d.ts`:

```js
// index.d.ts

declare module "@prisma/client" {
  import type { User as PrismaUser } from "@prisma/client/index";
  export * from "@prisma/client/index";

  export type Role = "ADMIN" | "MEMBER";
  export type User = Omit<PrismaUser, "role"> & { role: Role };
}
```

But it is only halfway working. When the type of a value is explicitly declared as `User`, it works as it should but when the `User` type comes from a Prisma client operation it uses the original type definition generated by Prisma where the `role` is of type `string`:

```js
import type { User, Role } from "@prisma/client";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const user1: User = {
  id: "123",
  email: "mail@test.com",
  role: "MEMBER",
  createdAt: new Date(),
  updatedAt: new Date(),
};
const role1: Role = user1.role; // This works, no complaints from TS

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const user2 = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: 'someId' } });
if(!user2) return;
const role2: Role = user2.role; // TS error: TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Role'
```

So it seems the old and new type definitions are merged in the second case and I have no idea why.